# Backup Import JS Module

Tags: javascript, import, module

I want to make a package a peer dependency and have a backup for its imported module if it doesn't exist

```
import { Bar } from 'foo';

const SafeBar = () => {};

if (Bar === undefined) {
  Bar = SafeBar
}
```

This errors for me when I try to do this though

Answer (score 0):

I used typeof and did a ternary